# How to remove all whitespace from all file and folder names recursively in OS X?

Tags: macos, shell, file-rename, batch-rename

I have in my project root directory files and folders, some of which have names with whitespace in them. I would like to rename all such files **AND** folders to remove all whitespace (from their names), recursively, under the current directory, in OS X. I tried several solutions suggesting  the `find` command, such as in the following, but I keep getting the same error assumingely because they use Linux's find, not OS X's.

**Command:**

```
find -name "* *" -print0 | sort -rz |   while read -d $'\0' f; do mv -v "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "${f// /_}")"; done
```

**Error:**

```
find: illegal option -- n
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
```

I get this error whether I execute the command in `bash` or `zsh`.

***Edit***: another answer suggested below (also using `find`) also doesn't work:

**Command:**
`find -depth -name "* *" -print0 -exec rename -0 's/\s+//g' {} \;`

**Error:**

```
find: illegal option -- e
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
```

And I also tried adding a path to the above command:
`find . -depth -name "* *" -print0 -exec rename -0 's/\s+//g' {} \;`

And it doesn't work, it prints `rename: No such file or directory` continuously for seemingly all the files/folders.

Comment: If you check `echo $SHELL` you are likely running zsh and not bash. (default on Catalina) zsh doesn't support literal strings, e.g. `$'\0'`

Comment: Oh that's strange, even though it says bash on the terminal: ```bash-3.2$ echo $SHELL``` the result is ```/bin/zsh```. However, unfortunately i still get the same exact error messages in bash (and I echoed to confirm I was on bash).

Comment: Still get ```rename: No such file or directory``` or the ```find: illegal option -- e``` errors on bash.

Comment: Also note there are TWO `rename` commands. (1) from the `util-linux` package that does not support `-0` (and a number of other options you will see used with `rename`) and (2) `perl-rename` which provides many options the `util-linux` `rename` doesn't. Distributions and OSs are split about 50/50 on which they use.

Comment: That command seemed to have appended all the file names together, and I got a ```File name too long``` error.

Comment: I'm on OS X. How do I know which rename command am I using? I tried ```which rename``` but didn't get any returned value.

Comment: I tried the above command, and although it printed many errors such as ```mv: rename ./2013-11-27 - to ./2013-11-27-: No such file or directory```, it worked for some of them.

Comment: You don't need `rename` if you use the command with `tr` I show above....

Comment: Try this ```mkdir rename_test;cd rename_test;mkdir folder\ 1; mkdir folder\ 1/folder\ 2;touch folder\ 1/hel\ lo.txt; touch folder\ 1/folder\ 2/\ \ hi.txt;touch \ \ space\ \ .txt```, and then run the command you typed. It didn't work for me in the nested files and folders.

Comment: I see what is happening. It renames `folder1` and `space.txt` just fine, but then after renaming `'folder 1'` -> `folder1`, it continues to try and renames files/folders below  `'folder 1'` -- which no longer exist because they are now named `folder1/...` I'll have to think on this a bit more.

Comment: You run into the same problem if you just try to operate on files alone, e.g. `'./folder 1/hel lo.txt'` to `'./folder1/hello.txt'` (note when the `' '` is removed from the dirname, you can no longer rename the file.) Here since you are not changing a fixed pattern in a filename, but randomly removing spaces, you will need to recursively change the directory names first, traversing to the lowest directory and working up -- then you can use a global change of the filenames. This will likely require a script rather than a one-liner...

Comment: Yes you're right. I was thinking I could use a regex to find the final file/folder name after the final ```/``` of the path depth first, but then the problem is if any of the files/folders have a ```/``` in their names the method would fail (regex can't differentiate between a '/' separating paths vs. in the actual file/folder name). I guess the only way to do it is by actually ```cd```ing into the available directories instead of referencing nested files by their full paths- that would solve the problem.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I wrote a Python script that seems to work as an answer, feel free to test it if you'd like :)

Comment: Which OS/distro/version ?

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh : I would do the file traversal depth-first, to avoid the problem outlined by DavidCRankin (option `-depth` on find). Also, be careful: With your approach, if you have a file named `ab cd`, and another one with `abcd`, you destroy the latter.

Comment: @Gilles Os X 10.15 Catalina.

Comment: @user1934428 I did try e.g. ```find . -depth -name "* *" -print0 -exec rename -n -0 's/\s+/_/g' {} \;``` and it didn't work. I get errors such as ```./folder 1Error: --null only permitted when reading filenames from STDIN```

Comment: Well, as you clearly see from the error message, this is not related to the usage of `-depth`, but from the way you combine `-print0` and `rename -0`, as you can see [here](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/).

Answer (score 1):

Since no terminal command works, I wrote a Python script that does it using recursion, some preliminary testing shows that it works. I made it ignore hidden folders/files (like .git). Tested it by entering

```
mkdir rename_test;cd rename_test;mkdir folder\ 1; mkdir folder\ 1/folder\ 2;touch folder\ 1/hel\ lo.txt; touch folder\ 1/folder\ 2/\ \ hi.txt;touch \ \ space\ \ .txt;mkdir \ \ \ \ myfolder\ \ \ 3;touch \ \ \ \ myfolder\ \ \ 3/file.txt;cd ..
```

And then running the script below, making sure `dirpath` points to the root directory of the root folder (in this case `rename_test`).

```
import os

#mkdir rename_test;cd rename_test;mkdir folder\ 1; mkdir folder\ 1/folder\ 2;touch folder\ 1/hel\ lo.txt; touch folder\ 1/folder\ 2/\ \ hi.txt;touch \ \ space\ \ .txt;mkdir \ \ \ \ myfolder\ \ \ 3;touch \ \ \ \ myfolder\ \ \ 3/file.txt;cd


def clean_dir(dirpath):
    os.chdir(dirpath)
    files = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('.'):
        files.extend(filenames)
        break
    files = [i for i in files if i[0] != '.'] #remove hidden files
    files = [i for i in files if ' ' in i] #only include files with space
    dirs = [name for name in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('.', name)) ]
    dirs = [i for i in dirs if i[0] != '.'] #remove hidden directories
    dirs = [i for i in dirs if ' ' in i] #only include dirs with space
    for i in files:
        os.system('mv ' + i.replace(' ', '\ ') + ' ' + ''.join(i.split()))
    for i in range(len(dirs)):
        os.system('mv ' + dirs[i].replace(' ', '\ ') + ' ' + ''.join(dirs[i].split()))
        dirs[i] = ''.join(dirs[i].split())
    for i in dirs:
        clean_dir(i)
        os.chdir('..')

dirpath = 'rename_test'
clean_dir(dirpath)
```

Note that it assumes there are no existing files with matching names (e.g. if there is a file called `a b c.txt` it assumes that there are no files called `abc.txt`. If there are I think it removes them.

Comment: Very good initiative in writing the script. I did test on your example and it works fine. (`tree rename_test` confirms) Writing in python is certainly shorter than writing in C with `nftw` or using a recursive function with `opendir()`/`readdir()`...

Answer (score -1):

Another (better/simpler/faster/stronger/shorter/smarter) approach:

First install **GNU** `findutils` via

```
brew install findutils
```

Then:

```
findutils . -depth -name "* *" -print0 -exec rename -n -0 's/\s+/_/g' {} \;
```

With `perl` rename.

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good.

## Note

The `-depth` here is very important, it traverse first files of directories before renaming directories themselves.

## Edit:

I added `.` (search PATH) to `find` command, because it's mandatory on some systems like `*BSD` and `OsX` !

Comment: I got ```find: illegal option -- e
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]```. Actually, even with just ```find -depth -name "* *"``` i get the error.

Comment: Try this ```mkdir rename_test;cd rename_test;mkdir folder\ 1; mkdir folder\ 1/folder\ 2;touch folder\ 1/hel\ lo.txt; touch folder\ 1/folder\ 2/\ \ hi.txt;touch \ \ space\ \ .txt``` then run your command. It doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: I'm using PERL rename.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/595712/prepend-user-defined-string-to-all-files-and-folders-recursively-using-find-and?noredirect=1#595712

Comment: I first tried it with just ```find``` with -depth, it didn't work, it gave me errors such as ```./folder 1Error: --null only permitted when reading filenames from STDIN```. I then tried ```brew install findutils``` as you suggest, but for whatever reason I get ```-bash: findutils: command not found``` when I run your command, even though it seems like it downloaded successfully. I tried installing again but got ```Warning: findutils 4.7.0 is already installed and up-to-date```. I tried opening a new terminal too but still get ```-bash: findutils: command not found```

Comment: I also tried ```gfind . -depth -name "* *" -print0 -exec rename -n -0 's/\s+/_/g' {} \;``` but i still get the same error messages e.g.: ```./folder 1Error: --null only permitted when reading filenames from STDIN```